# Rails iteration (for unique ID's) and javascript, multiple forms in one view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails-app with multiple forms(edit-modals) in one (index)view. In order to avoid identical id's I gave every form and every field a unique ID by using namespace:

```
<%= form_for(timing, namespace: index , html: { id: index}) do |f| %>
```

That works well and all fields have unique ID's.
Some of the fields use a js DateTime-picker that's related to the id's:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

$('#timing_start_time').periodpicker({...
```

Obviously that doesn't work anymore since the real ID's are now

```
0_timing_start_time, 1_timing_start_time ...
```

What's the right approach to have this js work for all id's for this field?

Thanks a lot in advance!